# Display form is messy

Tags: php, html, select

I try to tidy up the display form.

The page devided by 2 colomn. But when i input many of value or select, the display is messy. I have to set the "}" in anywhere but doesn't work.

This is the screenshot:[image]

**This is the code:**

```
<h3 class="form-section">Data Kegiatan</h3>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3"><b>Nama Proposal :</b></label>
         <div class="col-md-9">
            <p class="form-control-static"> <?php echo $proposalName; ?></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--/span-->
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3"><b>Jenis Bantuan :</b></label>
         <?php
            $no=0;
            $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_proposal_detail_jenis_bantuan WHERE proposalID='".$_GET['id']."'");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            while($new_arr=$stmt->fetch()){
                $stmt2 = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_jenis_bantuan WHERE jenisBantuanID='".$new_arr->jenisBantuanID."'");
                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                while($data=$stmt2->fetch()){
                    $no++;
            ?>
         <div class="col-md-9">
            <p class="form-control-static"> <?php echo $no.". ". $data->Name;?></p>
         </div>
         <?php }} ?>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--/span-->
</div>
<!--/row-->
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3"><b>Detail Bantuan:</b></label>
         <div class="col-md-9">
            <p class="form-control-static"> <?php echo $supportDetail; ?> </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--/span-->
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3"><b>Sub Sektor:</b></label>
         <?php
            $no=0;
            $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_proposal_detail_sub_sektor WHERE proposalID='".$_GET['id']."'");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            while($new_arr=$stmt->fetch()){
                $stmt2 = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_sub_sektor WHERE subSektorID='".$new_arr->subSektorID."'");
                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                while($data=$stmt2->fetch()){
                    $no++;
            ?>
         <div class="col-md-9">
            <p class="form-control-static"> <?php echo $no.". ".$data->subSektorName;?></p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <?php }} ?>
   </div>
   <!--/span-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all those label tag inside a div container something as:

```
<div class = "col-md-3">
  <label class="control-label"><b>Detail Bantuan:</b></label>
<div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <p class="form-control-static"> <?php echo $no.". ". $data->Name;?></p>
</div>
```

This is just an example put all those label in `"col-md-3"`container. This should work.

Comment: Thanks @Saroj Shrestha

Answer (score 0):

This is the cause:

This Code

```
<div class="col-md-9">
```

is include in Looping. I just take that code out of looping. And its Work. Thanks!